# Configure TraceSource for .NET Core application via configuration file

Tags: .net, .net-core, trace

I see that [TraceSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracesource?view=netcore-3.0) is available for .Net Core 3, but is there a way to configure the listeners, switches and filters through a configuration file w.o the need to manually map the configuration values (e.g. from appsettings.json) to the instance of the corresponding classes as in .Net Framework?

Comment: It seems that reading from configuration file is not supported for `TraceSource` now. See the discussions https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24829#issuecomment-547089706 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5982

Comment: Thanks @Didgeridoo for pointing out! I spotted it too, but I'm looking at least for a helper that do the bindings in favor to me :)

Comment: Looks like they have replacement for TraceSource -- DiagnosticSource https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/DiagnosticSourceUsersGuide.md